# need to create an array in a php file, and add values to it every time I call that php file through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create an array in a php file, and add values to it (like $array[] = something) every time I call that php file through ajax

I have tried with global and sessions, but doesn't work I have something like this in the file:

$_GET['index'] is changed every time the php is called from the javascript (ajax) code.

```
if(isset($_GET['value']) && isset($_GET['next']) && isset($_GET['actl']) && isset($_GET['index'])){
  $_SESSION['filters'][$_GET['index']]['id_feature'] = $_GET['actl'];
  $_SESSION['filters'][$_GET['index']]['value'] = $_GET['value'];

  print_r($_SESSION['filters']);
}
```

Problem is that resets its values and always shows the last values added to the array.

please excuse me for my english

Comment: Did you call `session_start()`?

Comment: no I didn't, where should I do that, at the beginning of the file? is there a problem if that function is used in other files?, I mean, it resets the sessions variables?

Comment: Call it before you start using anything to do with sessions. At the beginning of the file is usually a good place. Multiple calls to `session_start` should be no problem but you shouldn't really be having that issue if you design your scripts well.

Comment: is there a way to do this without using sessions?

Comment: isset takes multiple parameters so you can do `isset($_GET['value'],$_GET['next'],$_GET['actl'],$_GET['index'])`

Comment: Maybe, I don't know the full scope of what you're building. If it's just a filter you can probably do it in JavaScript. If you need to _remember_ the filter you could also use cookies since this data can be exposed (no security risk).

Answer (score 1):

*not an answer, just a comment with a lot of code*

This:

```
$a = array();
$a[]['id_feature'] = $_GET['actl'];
$a[]['value'] = $_GET['value'];
```

Will probably do this:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        "id_feature" => "foo"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "value" => "bar"
    )
)
```

But, you probably want to get this:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        "id_feature" => "foo",
        "value" => "bar"
    )
)
```

Write it like:

```
$a = array();
$a[] = array(
    'id_feature' => $_GET['actl'],
    'value' => $_GET['value']
);
```